# How to store threads in arraylist

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, arraylist

I have a server and several clients. I have created a thread for each client. I want to store thread or object of each client in an arraylist. And perform operations on it.

```
ArrayList<Client> clients;
Thread client = new Thread(new ClientThread(socket));
```

want to add each client in arraylist of clients. I have made an object arraylist of clients.

Comment: Is `ClientThread` a `Client`?

Comment: Client thread is not client. Thats a class used for multithreading using runnable. There r 3 classes Server Client and ClientThread

Comment: So what is `Client`? Where does it come from? Why do you want to add it to an `ArrayList`? How is it related to the thread you've shown? There's a lot missing from your question.

Comment: I just wanted to add threads in arraylist

Comment: _want to add each client in arraylist of clients_ Which one is it?

Comment: Maybe my declaration of arraylist is wrong. In second line i am creating a thread using socket. I want to store it somewhere so i am using arraylist.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89118/discussion-between-sam-and-sotirios-delimanolis).

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you have `ClientThread` defined somewhere where it implements `Runnable` you could do:

```
List<Thread> clients = new ArrayList<Thread>();
Thread client = new Thread(new ClientThread(socket));
client.start(); //assuming you want the thread to start
//running before you put into the arrayList
clients.add(client);
```

Comment: while adding it says non static variable client cannot be referenced from static context. Line 3

Comment: Thread client = new Thread(new ClientThread(socket));
                client.start();
                clients.add(client);